# Use grep -lr output to add files to tar

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grep, centos, tar

In UBUNTU and CENTOS.

I have some files I want to tar based on their contents.

```
$ grep -rl "123.45" .
```

returns a list of about 10 files in this kind of format:

```
./somefolder/someotherfolder/somefile.txt
./anotherfolder/anotherfile.txt
```

etc...

I want to tar.gz all of them.

I tried:

```
$ grep -rl "123.45" . | tar -czf files.tar.gz
```

Doesn't work. That's why I'm here. Any ideas? Thanks.

Just tried this, and it worked in Ubuntu, but in CentOS I get "tar: 02: Cannot stat: No such file or directory".

```
$ tar -czf test.tar.gz `grep -rl "123.45" .`
```

If anyone else has a better way, let me know. That above one works great in Ubuntu, at least.

Answer (score 9):

Like this:

```
 ... | tar -T - -czf files.tar.gz
```

"-T -" causes tar to read filenames from stdin. Second minus stands for stdin. –

Comment: can you explain that please? it worked, but need more info to win an upvote

Comment: @AlexandreReisRibeiro:  "-T -"  causes tar to  read filenames from stdin.   Second minus stands for stdin.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -rl "123.45" . | xargs tar -czf files.tar.gz
```

Comment: If you happen to have enough files matching the grep, `xargs` will invoke tar twice and the second time will overwrite the file created by the first.

Comment: I tried this and got "cannot stat: no such file or directory" on CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

Tar wants to be told what files to process, not given the names of the files via stdin.

It does however have a `-T` / `--files-from` option.  So I'd suggest using that.  Output your list of selected files to a temp file and then have tar read that, like this:

```
T=$(mktemp)
grep -rl "123.45" . > $T
tar cfz files.tar.gz -T $T
rm -f $T
```

If you want, you can also use shell expansion to do it like this:

```
tar cfz files.tar.gz -- $(grep -rl "123.45" .)
```

But that will fail if you have too many files or if any of the files have strange names (like spaces etc).

Comment: What about the solution I added to the bottom of my question?

Comment: @ButtleButkus - The back tick character mostly the same as the `$()` syntax, they are both forms of command expansion.  There are a few small differences and I personally prefer the `$()`, but your solution will work for most cases.  As I mentioned above, it will fail if too many files match or if any of those files have spaces in the filename.

Comment: Strange. "My" solution worked on Ubuntu. But I am getting errors in CentOS. And I get the same errors from your suggestion. I tried `tar -czf files.tar.gz -- $(grep -rl "123.45" .)`  - notice I added the dot. But, same errors. "Cannot stat: No such file or directory".

Comment: @ButtleButkus, you are correct the missing "." was a mistake.  I have fixed it.  The error you are getting could be a couple of things: the current directory might be invalid, maybe you have a space or other special character in a matching file, or maybe files are being deleted between the grep finding them and the tar trying to read them.  Running the grep manually should help figure out the case.